# Normal distribtion (a little confused?)

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

On a particular day, 50% of the employees arrive at work by 8.30 am, and 10% had not arrived by 8.55 am.

Assuming a normal model, find the standard deviation of the arrival times, in minutes?

What I tried: From what I understand, 40% of the people showed up in the gap of 25 minutes. Therefore, taking the difference between 0.90 - 0.50 = 0.40.

My query is how will I form an equation that I can solve because I don't have a x-bar, mean and standard deviation (3 unknowns?)

Comment: Thanks for specifying what you have already tried. This sounds like a homework or some type of self-directed study; if so, please add the `self-study` tag to the question. Such questions are encouraged on this site, but please read the [info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) that explains how we try to provide help.

Comment: @EdM tag is added. Not a homework question - its a self-study one.

Comment: I guess the leftover probability mass from the previous day is too small to matter? Just noting that a normal distribution is an odd choice here,  because it would imply that people could in theory turn up for work of a future day before they are even born or a past day well after their death. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As median = mean for the normal distribution you know that: $$\mu\hat{=}\text{8:30}$$.

Now the question is how to deal with the time Data on a numeric scale. But if we only want to find out the sd in minutes we could simply define that 8:30 corresponds to $830$. And e.g. 9:30 would be $830+60=890$ as 9:30 is $60$ minutes later. But we could equally well set 8:30 to $0$ and $9:30$ to $60$ (the difference is still measured in minutes), this change would not alter the sd.

Furthermore you know (using 8:30 corresponds to $830$) that $$\Phi_{830,\sigma ^2}(855)=0.9$$ (denoting with $\Phi_{\mu,\sigma ^2}$ the distribution function of a $N(\mu, \sigma ^2)$

This is equivalent to

$$\Phi_{0,1}(\frac{855-830}{\sigma})=0.9$$

Now you only have to apply the inverse oh the distribution function of the $N(0,1)$ and solve for $\sigma$

Comment: So basically mu = 8.30?

Comment: Yes because 50% arrive before 8.30 and therefore 50% After 8.30. This means that the Median is 8.30 and as Median = mean for normal distributions you know that mean = 8.30

Comment: My sigma value comes out to be 0.194. Their value is 19.50. Why is an *100 difference here? Do they expect to take 830 and not 8.30?

Comment: Yes because they ask for sd in minutes. Sorry, I should have paid attention to that

Comment: Be careful with your notation, I don't think 8.30 makes sense for the mean. Orangetree suggests $\mu = 830$ as in $830$ minutes. If you want to convert this (and Im not recommending you do), then this becomes $8.50$ since $30$ minutes is half of an hour. This should also explain why your answer $0.194$ is not equal to $19.5/100$.

Answer (score 2):

The normal probability distribution has several nice properties that can help resolve your confusion. Consider in particular its symmetry: half of the cases have values lower than the mean of the distribution (the median equals the mean). So you do have information about the mean of the distribution of arrival times. You also have information about the 90th percentile of arrival times, when 10% hadn't yet arrived. That's enough information to estimate the standard deviation based on normal probability tables.

Comment: Yes, I do know about this property. But there is only a 'timing' given. How do I convert that into a mean? Will mean be 30?